# Why doesn´t my toast message show on the home screen when phone is disconnected?

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, toast

I am developing a windows phone 8.1 app and I am trying to display a toast message whenever the phone receives a websocket message from the a server.

When the phone is connected to my laptop via an usb cable, everything works as expected. The toast shows when the app is active, and on the home screen when the app is inactive. I can click the toast and open the app. Everything also works fine when running the app on the emulator in Visual Studio 2013.

But when the phone is disconnected from the usb cable, the toast is only displayed when the app is open and not on the home screen.

The code to display the toast:

```
...
await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
{
    showToast();
}

...

private void showToast()
{
    var toastNotifier = ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier();
    var toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(ToastTemplateType.ToastText01);
    var toastText = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
    (toastText[0] as XmlElement).InnerText = "New alarm arrived.";
    var toast = new ToastNotification(toastXml);
    toastNotifier.Show(toast);
}
```

The app is set to be "toast capable" in the app manifest.

Phone setting also looks fine to me:

- Settings->notifications+actions: On: Banners, Sounds, Vibrations.

The behavior is reproducible. Changing phone settings does not help and I can´t find anything helpful in Microsoft's own documentation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try anything so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) as a start.

Comment: Thanks. Love Stack Overflow; it´s an amazing source of knowledge. I´ll rephrase the question and make it better. And believe me; I have tried to solve this. :)

Comment: Is battery saving mode enabled? Are other apps getting notifications?